# javascript where to put the var statement

Tags: javascript

I have a function that looks like this:

```
function SomeFunction() {

  var SomeVar;

  if (SomeCondition) {
     SomeVar = 4;
  }
}
```

This is equivalent to:

```
function SomeFunction() {

  if (SomeCondition) {
     var SomeVar = 4;
  }
}
```

Does using the var statement only if the condition is true make a difference or not, is there any best practice or **performance implications** concerning this?

Thanks.

**Edit: yes, I am aware that there's no block scope, just function scope.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are both actually equivalent. Read up on ["hoisting"](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting) and ["function and block scope"](http://augustli.wordpress.com/2011/04/05/javascript-pitfalls-no-block-scope/).

As far as speed goes, you're better off using the second case - combining the declaration and assignment in the same statement. See: http://jsperf.com/stackoverflow-frenchie

Comment: The JSPerf really looks like they're about the same (so far) with an exception for what really looks like an outlier for one run in Opera.

Comment: See http://jsperf.com/stackoverflow-frenchie/2 I've added a few more runs of the function to simulate the case where functions are called more often than they're defined.  I also added the base case where no variable is ever set.  My results would imply that placing a declaration at the top is not only faster than in the block, it's faster than not even doing an assignment!  I'd really say there are no real performance implications.

Answer (score 4):

They function exactly the same, but there are two schools of thought about where to put it:

One group says you should put it at the top of the function, because that avoids the false impression you are relying on (nonexistent) block-scoping.

The other group says you should put it in the appropriate block, because that signals you intend to treat the variable as if it were block-scoped and not use it anywhere else.

As far as I know, I am the sole member of the second group.

Comment: +1 - Makes sense to me to declare the variable as if it were in a block scope if that's how you intend to use it.

Comment: I wish I could give you a second upvote for your last statement.

Comment: @frenchie -- the parse phase might be fractionally slower, but I doubt it and in any case, it would take millions of lines of code before the difference was noticeable. Once the code is actually running, there is absolutely no difference.  BTW, are you [this](http://www.debbieschlussel.com/archives/frenchy.jpg) Frenchie?

Answer (score 3):

Where the `var` statement is put has no effect on your code.  This is purely a matter of style.

Some people feel that it's much clearer to put the `var` at the start of the `function` block.  The lifetime of a variable in Javascript is tied to the function in which it's declared and not the scope.  Many other curly brace languages do the opposite and this is a source of confusion for many new users.  Hence people believe declaring at the start of the function leads to clearer code.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, there is no block scope for variables like in C/C++. Therefore, even if you declare your variable in the `if () {}` block, the variable is actually created immediately at the beginning of the function. This effect of "pulling declarations up" is usually called "hoisting".

Although both codes are correct, the first one is probably semantically better, as it emphasizes the fact that the variable exists regardless of whether `SomeCondition` is true.

Answer (score 0):

Put it at the beginning of the function. It is always moved there anyway during the runtime, but it clears the confusion / untrue assumption if you put it where it is really executed.

So in you case, the first snippet.

(also, purely style, write identifier of everything except classes camelCase, not PascalCase)

Comment: It is the same, the second snippet is in fact always interpreted as if it were the first one (but you can draw some bug-leading assumption from the second one). It is called "var hoisting", as others pointed out.

Comment: @frenchie Speaking just with regards to file size, manually hoisting could be 2 bytes heavier per declaration in a minified file, but grouping them together enables you or the compiler to get a 4 byte file size reduction when you combine `var` definitions.  There's probably something on JSPerf testing this out but I'll generalize that micro-optimizations like this would make almost no difference in either direction.